# What happens to fields you mark [NonSerialized] when you deserialize?

Tags: c#, deserialization

Are these fields set to default values like when a new instance is created?  Can I create custom code to set these fields to new values upon deserialization?

Comment: +1, interesting question. Should be easy to test though, surely?

Comment: @Pete - well I did have a pretty good hunch about the first part ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note: all of this is specific to `BinaryFormatter`:

By default, they are ignored completely; they will have their type-default values, i.e. a zero-value / null-value.

If you implement custom serialization (`ISerializable`), then `[NonSerializable]` doesn't apply, and you can do what you want, but most people *don't want* to have to do this. However, you can also implement `IDeserializationCallback`, which provides an ideal opportunity to initialize such fields:

```
[Serializable]
class Foo : IDeserializationCallback
{
    // ... not shown
    void IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization(object sender)
    {
        // init your [NonSerialized] fields here
    }
}
```

Note that other serializers have *different* implementations for serialization callbacks, some of which are *also* supported by `BinaryFormatter`, for example:

```
[Serializable]
class Foo
{
    // ... not shown
    [OnDeserializing]
    private void AnyMethodName(StreamingContext c)
    {
        // init your [NonSerialized] fields here
    }
}
```

The attribute-based callbacks provide more opportunities to inject code at specific points, and are usually preferred. There are 4: `[OnDeserializing]`, `[OnDeserialized]`, `[OnSerializing]` and `[OnSerialized]`.

Comment: @Paul and I even managed to make it through the answer without adding, "oh, and btw; don't use `BinaryFormatter` - at all". Damn, now I've gone and ruined it. (and no, that isn't a joke - my advice is always: don't use that)

Answer (score 0):

When a new instance is creted this fields are default value of type.

You can set set your custom values on object construct

Comment: If by "on object construct" you mean the constructor, then that doesn't work. The field will be reset afterwards to default.