# Locking two objects without deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have a question that is easily solvable in C++, but in C# I still can’t find a good solution:

I have a function foo that need to lock two objects and this function can be called with arguments in the opposite order, e.g.:

```
    static void foo(object o1, object o2)
    {
        lock (o1)
        {
            lock (o2)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    static void bar(object a, object b)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s => foo(a, b));
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s => foo(b, a));
    }
```

This is a by-the-book way to make a deadlock. The standard way to fix this is to always lock objects in the same order. In C++, I could compare pointers but in “safe” C# I don’t know any way but a very ugly `Monitor.TryEntry` solution (see below). Is there anything better? Please note that objects are mutable and I can’t rely on `Equals`, `GetHashCode`, `IComparable`.

```
    static void foo(object o1, object o2)
    {
        const int Timeout = 1000;
        while (true)
        {
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(o1, Timeout))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Monitor.TryEnter(o2, Timeout))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ...
                            return;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            Monitor.Exit(o2);
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(o1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any control over the code that cals this function?  Can you change it to pass the objects in an order that will not deadlock?

Comment: No, order can be arbitrary. I knew I had to order objects somehow but I'm still hoping there is a solution where I don't have to add "id" field to those objects (or wrap them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the same ordered lock approach you can add some property to the object you are using for locking and compare based on it. You can use classes or interfaces depending what works in your case (i.e. implement `IComparable` on locking objects). Sample below uses class with `Less` comparing function:

```
class ComparableLockingObject
{
    static int LastOrderValue = 0;
    private orderValue = LastOrderValue++;

    public bool Less(ComparableLockingObject other)
    {
       return this.orderValue < other.orderValue;
    }
}

static void foo(ComparableLockingObject o1, ComparableLockingObject o2,
    Action action)
{
   if (o2.Less(o1))
   {
      var temp = o1;
      o1 = o2;
      o2 = temp;
   }

   lock (o1)
   {
        lock (o2)
        {
           action();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An `int` may not guarantee unique ranking.  I'd suggest a `long`, obtained via `Interlocked.Increment`.

Comment: If the class can be altered with new ID field, then looks like this is the way to go. If not, looks like there is no solution yet.

Comment: Note that if object has `Serialiazable`/`DataContract` attribute, you need to specify on-deserializing callback to properly initialize `orderValue` in order to make this approach work. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456571/what-happens-to-fields-you-mark-nonserialized-when-you-deserialize) for example.

Comment: This is pretty questionable,  it could only work safely if the objects are not already locked.  The only way to be sure is to lock them.  Giving you the exact same problem back again.

Comment: @HansPassant - I'd not be surprised if this does not work, but could you please elaborate more on the issue? `ComparableLockingObject` is immutable, so not sure where the problem would is.

Comment: Worked fine actually, I added an id field but had to set it on deserialization. But still the solution looks better than TryEnter with timeouts.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to lock these objects. You lock the code that executes the logic:

```
  static object lockObject = new object();
  static void foo(object o1, object o2)
  {
     lock (lockObject)
     {
        // this code will be executed on one thread at the time. Why lock o1 & o2??
     }
  }
```

Comment: I do need to lock those objects and I can't change that. They can be updated in different threads at the same time (they will be locked during update) so this approach won't work.

Comment: On a second thought, I could use this static lock before I lock those two objects and it would fix the deadlock issue, but then `foo` calls can't run in parallel at the same time with other objects which is not great.

Comment: You can put locking mechanism within your foo objects if you fear your instance will be accessed from multiple threads. And then, you can control, when execution is done.

Comment: This solution kills concurrency between `foo(a,b)` and `foo(c,d)`.

Comment: Concurrency can be taken care of by some sort of registration